# length of list element return always 1 in R

Tags: r

I'm working with R and i have a `data.frame` like that:

```
package     depend
ABCoptim        
ALDEx2      methods 1
ALKr        R (>= 2.15.2)   1
ARAMIS      R (>= 2.15.0), MASS, LearnBayes, methods, graphics
```

and i want for each package count the number of `depend`.

So, i made a loop to iterate my data frame, and  i turn each depend of package to list, then i try with length  to have the number of element but i always have 1 like result.
helps please. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find solution by adding "Strsplit" in each depend of package.